# Network filesystem client moving between networks

Tags: laptop, sshfs

At home, I have a network drive and devices that mount it from a local IPv4 address. Away, my laptop mounts that same drive with sshfs and a DNS-resolvable hostname.

Moving the laptop from network to network is still a problem. I never remember to unmount the filesystem before closing the laptop (and who would?). Shells become unresponsive, lock the mount point, and generally make it a fuss to get back to work.

I imagine the system silently remounting as needed, ideally without interrupting processes with open files. Perhaps this process could be triggered by a wifi rule that runs a certain script upon every network affiliation.

Is there a best practice or a better way to look at this problem?

Answer (score 2):

For this purpose I use [autofs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs).

> `autofs` is a program for automatically mounting directories on an as-needed basis. Auto-mounts are mounted only as they are accessed, and are unmounted after a period of inactivity.

The actual mounting is done via VPN to my home router; this way I mount the same share existing at the same address, regardless whether I'm away or at home (relevant: my router supports [hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning)).

In my case it's plain NFS mount without authentication, the whole security is at VPN level. Autofs can handle other mounts, see [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1233287/432690) where it was used with `cifs`.

---

Another possibility is systemd automount (see this question: [Systemd automount vs autofs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/374103/108618)) but I have never used it yet.

Answer (score 2):

The way I solve this problem - the practicality of which depends on your network architecture - is to make extensive use of OpenVPN - and by accessing the devicesthrough IPs which are reachable through the VPN if the underlying IP addresses change it does not matter - OpenVPN reconnnects with the same internal IPs and the TCP session resume.