# fstab noauto, but automatic if you click on folder

Tags: linux, mount, nfs, fstab

I have a notebook here and network shares. Normally I would want to get them mounted on boot, but this wouldn't be so good on a notebook which isn't allways connected to the right network. So I put an "noauto" in the fstab.

```
<IP>:/share              /share        nfs     noauto,defaults        0 0
```

But if I'm connected to the right network, I don't want to allways have to mount the share manually. Is there a way to let it mount when I click on the folder, like with an USB drive? Or any other ideas how to let it mount when the notebook is in the correct network?

Hope you can help out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Network filesystem client moving between networks](https://superuser.com/questions/1275342/network-filesystem-client-moving-between-networks)

Comment: thanks, I looked into it. but either I'm stupid or nothing works. I installed autofs and configured it like the documentation suggests, but nothing works:

/etc/default/autofs:
/net -hosts --timeout=60
/share    /etc/auto.share

/etc/auto.share:
/share <ip>:/share

or 

/share -fstype=nfs,rw,retry=0 <ip>:/share

(both didnt work)

Comment: You won't get help based only on this ill-formatted comment. Even a properly formatted comment is not a good place to seek help. I think you have two constructive options: (1) Either you [edit] the question and change its scope, so it becomes a question about configuring `autofs` (note in general you shouldn't change scope if there is any answer; act before somebody answers the current question then). (2) Or you let this question be and ask a separate one. // It's up to you. Either way the new problem should be introduced as a question, not just a comment. Take our short [tour] maybe.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the `nofail` option and remove `no-auto`. This will add auto-mounting at boot when you are connected, but not give you problems when it fails to mount.

Then, the simplest next step would be just to call
`mount <mount-point directory>`
When you are connected to the network, but not mounted.  If this is burdensome, you could put that into a short script or assign a bash alias to that command.

A fancier, more automated alternative would be to run a script when any connection is made.  You could run a cron job that runs a script every x amount of time:

```
#!/bin/bash
 if [[ $(cat /sys/class/net/<device 1>/carrier) == 1 ]] && [[ -z $(grep -s '<mount-point directory> ' /proc/mounts) ]]; then
    mount <mount-point directory>
 fi
```

This checks if you have a connection and mounts if you are not already mounted.

Answer (score 0):

I currently use the following approach:

1. Create a desktop entry file.
2. When you need your network share, just double-click an icon on the desktop instead of manually mounting via terminal.
3. Type your password. This is once per login session only.
4. Behold your network share in a file manager.

Now the desktop entry file (`~/Desktop/nas.desktop`):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=nas
Exec=sh -c "findmnt /mnt/nas || pkexec mount 192.168.1.15:/ /mnt/nas && nemo /mnt/nas"
Comment=Mount and open NAS shared dir
Terminal=false
Icon=folder-remote
Type=Application
```

`sh -c ...` is just a wrapper for multiple commands here making them a single one, because desktop entries don't always work with multiple commands.

`findmnt ...` checks whether a mount point is... well, mounted or not. If it is already then the next one command is skipped.

`pkexec ...` executes the `mount` command as superuser, asking you for a password in a "GUI way", like `sudo` in terminal.

`nemo` is a file manager (I use linux mint).

Among disadvantages of this way is that you have to get to your desktop (Ctrl+D), and you'll get a new file manager window instead of just a new tab in the one already opened, and you still have to type your password. That's why I'm currently looking for a better solution. If I find it, I'll post it here.

Comment: Thats a good way, think I'm going to use that. For the password, couldnt you just put  "<user> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/mount" in your /etc/sudoers file? Maybe not the most secure thing, but I think a good compromise.